# How to use a generated kubeconfig file in the .kube/config

Tags: kubernetes, kubeconfig

I am using digital ocean to deploy a managed kubernetes cluster and it gives me a config file to download. How do I use the downloaded .yaml file with my default config file in /.kube directory?

I tried to merge the config files, but it did not work. Is there any easy way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which configuration file to use with your `kubectl` command by adding the `--kubeconfig` flag.